# How to Merge Multi Table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 talbe:

*** ps_currency

```
id      name
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
```

*** rate_sell

```
id_currency      RateSell
1                10
2                20
```

*** rate_buy

```
id_currency      RateBuy
2                25
3                30
4                40
```

How to select to output

```
id      name     RateBuy       RateSell
1       A        NULL          10
2       B        25            20
3       C        30            NULL
4       D        40            NULL
```

Thanks,

Comment: They are called "joins"... go do some research

Comment: I did but I cannot found correct answer. Please help me if you can :)

Comment: Google "mysql join", [this is the first result](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Can you write a command for me? I tried but it don't work

Comment: In general, no, you can't ask people to write your code. If you show what you've tried and in what way it "don't work", people may be prepared to help you spot your error. But "gimmethecode" questions are usually not well received.

Comment: I tried

SELEC ps_currency.* FROM ps_currency
LEFT JOIN rate_buy WHERE rate_buy.id = ps_currency.id

but it only show 

    id_currency      RateSell
    1                10
    2                20

Comment: next time update the question with what you have tryed not with a comment.

Answer (score 2):

> **Copy paste from comment**
>   I tried SELECT ps_currency.* FROM ps_currency LEFT JOIN rate_buy WHERE
>   rate_buy.id = ps_currency.id but it only show id_currency RateSell 1
>   10 2 20

You need to use LEFT JOIN with a ON clause to make LEFT JOIN´s work properly

**Query**

```
 SELECT 
    ps_currency.id
  , ps_currency.name
  , rate_buy.RateBuy
  , rate_sell.RateSell
FROM 
  ps_currency

LEFT JOIN 
 rate_buy
ON
 ps_currency.id = rate_buy.id_currency

LEFT JOIN 
 rate_sell
ON 
  ps_currency.id = rate_sell.id_currency

ORDER BY
 ps_currency.id ASC
```

**Result**

```
| id | name | RateBuy | RateSell |
|----|------|---------|----------|
|  1 |    A |  (null) |       10 |
|  2 |    B |      25 |       20 |
|  3 |    C |      30 |   (null) |
|  4 |    D |      40 |   (null) |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0a23d/11